# Writing a join to get customers within a certain distance of a given zip code

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: ZipCodes and customers.

ZipCodes has columns for `lng` and `lat`, and customers have a `zipcode`.

I need a query to get all customers with in a certain distance of `XXXXX` zipcode.

I have a query to get me all the zipcodes within a certain distance of XXXXX:

```
SELECT ZIPCODE,( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( $la ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LAT ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LNG ) - RADIANS( $lo ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( $la ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM ZipCodes 
HAVING distance <$rad 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

I just do not know how the joins work or how to word this in SQL. If you could explain any answer provided I would appreciate it as well. If not I understand that too.

My logic is this:

```
SELECT name FROM Customers WHERE Customers.zipcode = ( SELECT ZIPCODE,( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( $la ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LAT ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LNG ) - RADIANS( $lo ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( $la ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM ZipCodes 
HAVING distance <$rad 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20)
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Something like this should work assuming your original query returned what it was supposed to:

```
SELECT Customers.* 
FROM Customers C 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ZIPCODE,( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( $la ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LAT ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LNG ) - RADIANS( $lo ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( $la ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM ZipCodes 
    HAVING distance <$rad 
    ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
) as RelevantCodes 
  ON (C.ZipCode=RelevantCodes.ZipCode)
```

Comment: YOU are the man! I just went and played with it to understand. I understand inner join, outer join, full join and all but I see what you did as making my results look like another table with "as RelevantCodes" which makes it a piece of cake to understand now. I REALLY appreciate your response.

Comment: BTW: This construct in SQL is known as a derived table. There are other ways to solve your problem, but this seemed the easiest to understand if you are just starting out.

Comment: People are voting this question down. I thought I could come to this forum for help. I did not know it was for professional developers ONLY! I appreciate the added note John and all of your help.

Comment: That's not why they are down-voting. It is somewhat of a RTFM question, honestly, and appears that you really didn't try that hard on your own to read up on joins before asking. Just sayin'

Comment: In searching for an answer knowing what you are searching for is 90% of the battle. If someone doesn't know what they are searching for, I think that is being stuck. Before I got into programming I was heavily involved virus removal forums helping out. I never voted down a question because someone did not know where their control panel was, they literally were that bad with computers. I could have spent 4-5 days researching and learning about joins and figured that out, but I thought a forum like this is meant to not have to do that and with professionals, its an easy question. My 2 cents.

Comment: 4-5 days? Google "SQL Joins" and you get a page full of results including this: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm

Don't get upset, but the community just prefers when people show that they tried to find the answer on their own, or at least tried a few google searches first.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that zipcodes are not round or small, precision cannot be very good - you should be aware of that.

Also, since Earth circumference is 40000km, it means that 1 degree of latitude or longitude is 10000 / 90 ~= 111km.

Having this, this query should work well provided that distance is less than half of Earth (10000 km or less):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT c.*,
       (   SELECT
              sqrt(pow(mod(360+lat -z.lat, 360),2)
                 + pow(mod(360+long-z.long,360),2)
              ) * 111   -- exact value is 10000 km/90 degrees
           FROM zipcodes
           WHERE zipcode = $zipcode
       ) AS distance
    FROM customers c
    JOIN zipcodes z ON (z.zipcode = c.zipcode)
) x
WHERE distance < $distance_km
ORDER BY distance
```